# Stuck trying to figure out Rails association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, database-migration

I have two models - `User` and `Network`. In my case, each `User` can have many `Network` and each `Network` can have many `User` and belongs to one `User` (the one who created).

For example, let's say there is  `User 1` with two networks `N1` and `N2`. The network `N1` has `User 2` and the network `N2` has `User 3`.

What I want to achieve is the `creator` field of `N1` and `N2` will give me `User 1` and the `users` field of `N1` will give me `[User 2]` and that of `N2` will give me `[User 3]`

I can have the creator field with foreign key, and I know I can use a `has_many through:` relation to figure out which networks contain which users and which users belong to which networks. But in that case, is there a way to quickly tell if there is a relation between two users or not?

For example something like `user2.follows? user1` will return `true` since `User 2` belongs to a network of `User 1`. I can iterate through all the networks created by `User 1` and check if `User 2` belongs to it, but is there a better way?

Comment: Well, what exactly are you trying to identify them by?  All you have provided is that users are connected by networks, but you want to identify them without comparing them by networks?

Comment: @tblev yes, basically I want so that any user who belongs to a network of some other user will be related.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend include method,

you can use a method as follows `user1.N1.include?(user2)`

If this method is not the same you want it, please more specific example

Sure I understood, And, please try  pluck method,

```
User.join(:networks).where(id: user1.id).pluck(:belonged user2 column)
```

This means  I joint User and Network model, then find the user in where method,

Finally, search belonged user2 column

belonged user2 column is to identify the user2 in the network model,

Comment: We still have to go through the network. I want something like `user2.follows? user1` that can be done without iterating through every network by the user